# Read data from CSV and write data to CSV - String to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a CSV file with 100,000 rows.

Each row in column A is a sentence comprised of both chars and integers.

I want column B to contain only integers.

I want the new columns to be in the same CSV file.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Where's an example of the data? And, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I would use `.isdigit()` to parse the data in column A. I'm frankly not sure what the format of column A is, so I don't know exactly what you would do with this (if you gave more information I could give a more specific answer). Your solution will *likely* come in a similar form to this:

```py
def find(lines):
  B = []
  for line in lines:
    numbers = [c for c in line if c.isdigit()]
    current = int(''.join(numbers))
    # current is the concatenation of all 
    # integers found in column A from left to right
    B.append(current) 
  return B
```

Let me know if this makes sense or is even in the right track for your solution. Once again, without knowing what you're trying to do, and what A looks like, I'm not sure what your actual goals are.

**EDIT**

I'm not going to explain the csv stuff for you, mainly because there is a fantastic resource and library for it included in python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). If you have *specific* questions related to writing csv, definitely post them.

It sounds like you essentially want to pull int values out of column A then add them to a new column B. There are definitely many ways to solve this, but the general form of the problem is for each row you'll filter out the int, then you'll add the filtered int into the new column. I'll list a couple:

- Regex: You could use a pattern such as `[0-9]+` to pull the string out of A, then use int(*whatever that output is*) to cast to int, then store those values in B. I'm a sucker for a good regular expression and this one is fairly straight forward. [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) is a great resource to learn about this and test your pattern.
- Use an algorithm similar to above: The above algorithm worked before, but I've updated it slightly. Now that it's been updated it'll return an array of numbers correspondent to numbers in A from left to right. This is relatively sound, but it doesn't necessarily guarantee you have the right integer, given that if the title has an int in it, it'll mess some things up. It is likely one of the more clear ways of doing this, though.

Comment: My file name is test.csv. Column 'A' has rows with data like this. 'Tool cost for part no. 123456'   I want Column B to have only 123456.  There are 1 thousand rows and each row will have char and int.   I want output Column 'B' in test.csv.

Comment: Edited my answer